# Get table from website using VBA with dynamic web address

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, web

I'm trying to insert a table from a website into excel, specifically off of WSJ futures. There's a calendar feature I can get around by changing the web address. I would like to make the website in the code a cell reference so I can make the address dynamic. Below is the code for the regular macro with  no dynamic address. Suggestions on how to make this change? I've tried taking out the URL and making it a cell reference, but it did not work.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=Range("A1"), Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3023-fut_metal-futures-20170901.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data5 = Source{5}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data5,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Colu" & _
    "mn6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Top Rows"" = Table.Skip(#""Changed Type"",1)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#""Removed Top Rows"", [PromoteAllScalars=true])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 5"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 5]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_5"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is expected output? Please share a screenshot.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I have an internal web site that I use a varable number to get to, depending on the variable. My script writes the variable to R2, and I use a Concatenate statement to combine R1 (the URL) and R2 (variable). The contents of R1 is:  `=CONCATENATE("https://internalwebsite/Profiles/Edit?ProfileCode=",$R$2,"&ProfileType=0")`

Comment: How would you edit the code to read, for example, the contents of R1? I can create a formula that would pull the right web address, but the code won't work once i switch to that cell reference instead of the hard coded website.

Comment: Please show expected and what some of the other URLs are that you would be using? I can't see what on that page would allow you to make a different calendar selection....